# magento2 templates

Tags: magento2

I copied template folder's default header code from below path:

> /magento2/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates

pasted above copied template in my app path and reloaded page, but header didn't work.

> /magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento/twp/Magento_Theme/templates

Give me a proper guide please.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your templates under your own name, e.g.

/magento2/app/design/frontend/**twp**/twp-theme/Magento_Theme/templates

Apart from that you might need to clear cache etc.

Comment: magento2/app/design/frontend/Magento/twp/Magento_Theme/templates

Comment: i put this in my code

Comment: which template file have you copied?